# Getting output 0 even if there are 25 same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

[Image of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyAkH.png)

[Link to the page](https://www.holonis.com/excellenceaddiction)

I am trying to see how many of class are there on this page but the output is 0. And I have been using BeautifulSoup for a while but never saw such error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes")
c = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
samples = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ng-scope"})
print(len(samples))
```

Output

`0`

and I want the correct output at least more than 25

Comment: What would be your question?

Comment: There's no `ng-scope` anywhere in this file, so the output is correct...

Comment: @Psytho how could I get the output 25

Comment: Please avoid using external links. Build a sample HTML document and replicate the problem from that. I cannot, for instance, access that site while at work.

Comment: Well the page you are trying to access needs to have javascript running for it to display properly. Might need to find another library emulating a browser request.

Comment: That HTML image you posted (please don't do that, either, its really inefficient) is from your browser. Your browser has Javascript. As Pierre noted, those elements don't exist until Angular (which is Javascript) has a chance to run... which it can't without Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "dynamic" Angular-based page which *needs a Javascript engine or a browser to be fully loaded*. To put it differently - the HTML source code you see in the browser developer tools is not the same as you would see in the `result.content` - the latter is a non-rendered initial HTML of the page which does not contain the desired data.

You can use things like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to have the page rendered and loaded and then HTML-parse it, but, why don't make a **direct request to the site API**:

```
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.holonis.com/api/v2/activities/motivationquotes/all?limit=15&page=0")
data = result.json()

for post in data["items"]:
    print(post["body"]["description"])
```

Post descriptions are retrieved and printed for example-purposes only - the `post` dictionaries contain all the other relevant post data that is displayed on the web-page.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `result.content` does not contain any divs with `ng-scope` class. As stated in one of the comments the html you are trying to get is added there due to the javascript running on the browser.

I recommend you this package [requests-html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) created by the author of very popular [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests).

You can try to use the code below to build on that.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes')
r.html.render()
```

To see how many `ng-scope` classes are there just do this:

```
>>> len(r.html.find('.ng-scope'))
302
```

I assume you want to scrape all the `href`s from the `a` tags that are children of the divs you gave the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyAkH.png) to. You can obtain them this way:

```
divs = r.html.find('[ng-if="!isVideo"]')
link_sets = (div.absolute_links for div in divs)

>>> list(set(chain.from_iterable(link_sets)))
['https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes/o/byiqe-ydm',
 'https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes/o/rkhv0uq9f',
 'https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes/o/ry7ra2ycg',
 ...
 'https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes/o/sydzfwgcz',
 'https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes/o/s1eidcdqf']
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `BeautifulSoup`, in fact, the result of your `GET` request, does not contain any `ng-scope` text.

You can see the output here:

```html
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> result = requests.get("https://www.holonis.com/motivationquotes")
>>> c = result.content
>>> 
>>> print(c)
**Verify the output yourself**
```

Comment: OP's Question is asking to findall "ng-scope" your answer doesn't help achieve that .

Answer (score 0):

You only have `ng-cloak` class as you can see from the regex result:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('ng.*')

samples = soup.findAll("div", {"class": regex})
samples
#[<div class="ng-cloak slideRoute" data-ui-view="main" fixed="400" main-content="" ng-class="'{{$state.$current.animateClass}}'"></div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of that webpage, it is either wise to use their api or choose any browser simulator like `selenium`. That webpage loads it's content using lazyload. When you scroll down you will see more content. The webpage expands its content through pagination like `https://www.holonis.com/excellenceaddiction/1`. However, you can give this a go. I've created this script to parse content displayed within 4 pages. You can always change that page number to satisfy your requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://www.holonis.com/excellenceaddiction/{}"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #If necessary, define the path

for link in [URL.format(page) for page in range(1,4)]:
    driver.get(link)
    for items in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tile-content .tile-content-text'):
        print(items.text)

driver.quit()
```

Btw, the above script parses the `description` of each post.